# Docker run failing with syntax error after build successful

Tags: docker, dockerfile, open-policy-agent

I built the docker image locally in mac system and then when I'm trying to run the docker getting the below error. I tried both below options.

```
# Build OPA Service directory, load policies and data, install and run OPA daemon
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add curl  
ADD $PWD/data /data
VOLUME /data
RUN curl -L -o opa https://openpolicyagent.org/downloads/v0.46.1/opa_darwin_amd64
RUN chmod 755 ./opa 
EXPOSE 8181
CMD ./opa run -s ./data --skip-version-check
```

Docker Build Command

> docker build -t opaservice .
> Docker Run command I'm executing
> docker run opaservice
> Error Message logged
> ./opa: line 0: syntax error: unterminated quoted string

tried below changing from CMD to ENTRYPOINT but no luck

> ENTRYPOINT ["./opa" "run" "-s" "./data" "--skip-version-check"]

Comment: Have you tried to debug at all whether `opa` is actually an executable binary file?  `docker run --rm -it your-image sh` will get you a debugging shell in a temporary container (provided your Dockerfile uses `CMD` and not `ENTRYPOINT`).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate, It worked for me.

```
root@swarm01:/myworkspace/docker# cat Dockerfile
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
ADD $PWD/data /data
VOLUME /data
RUN curl -L -o opa https://openpolicyagent.org/downloads/v0.46.1/opa_darwin_amd64
RUN chmod 755 ./opa
EXPOSE 8181
#CMD ./opa run -s ./data --skip-version-check
ENTRYPOINT ["./opa" "run" "-s" "./data" "--skip-version-check"]
```

I create a empty data directory.

```
root@swarm01:/myworkspace/docker# mkdir data
root@swarm01:/myworkspace/docker# docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.56kB
Step 1/8 : FROM alpine:latest
 ---> bfe296a52501
Step 2/8 : RUN apk --no-cache add curl
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b535a243661d
Step 3/8 : ADD $PWD/data /data
 ---> 4be29d67af7c
Step 4/8 : VOLUME /data
 ---> Running in 508d5eb2331d
Removing intermediate container 508d5eb2331d
 ---> 3e4399d19162
Step 5/8 : RUN curl -L -o opa https://openpolicyagent.org/downloads/v0.46.1/opa_darwin_amd64
 ---> Running in bb11fb2a5316
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    81  100    81    0     0    414      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   415
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
100 57.8M  100 57.8M    0     0  6976k      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--  9.9M
Removing intermediate container bb11fb2a5316
 ---> b87791a27ae9
Step 6/8 : RUN chmod 755 ./opa
 ---> Running in f69cfcc4d253
Removing intermediate container f69cfcc4d253
 ---> a6e4cd0e6e34
Step 7/8 : EXPOSE 8181
 ---> Running in e48a8bf4aced
Removing intermediate container e48a8bf4aced
 ---> db4b8ba5fb95
Step 8/8 : ENTRYPOINT ["./opa" "run" "-s" "./data" "--skip-version-check"]
 ---> Running in e6cf0d68f2c8
Removing intermediate container e6cf0d68f2c8
 ---> b0f0ba930f81
Successfully built b0f0ba930f81
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked after changing URL to curl -L -o opa https://openpolicyagent.org/downloads/v0.46.1/opa_linux_amd64_static as per instructions from https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/#running-opa